# Data Syncronisation Solution

Tags: sync

I currently have a home grown RSync solution that syncs between multiple hosts eg. A --> B syncs a set of folders, B --> A syncs a different set of folders.

While the solution works it is hard to maintain and extend. RSync is ideal because:

- It only transfers what has changed
- I can run it on my own machines (I don't want to sync to / via the cloud)

I looked at the applications mentioned [Smart synchronization between 2 networked PCs](https://superuser.com/questions/56508/smart-syncronisation-between-2-networked-pcs) but they are either not easy to manage (by non technical users) or only sync in a single direction.

[TeamDrive](http://www.teamdrive.com/) seems a promising solution except the free solution has a 2GB limit.

I need to find a free or very cheap solution as there is no budget for this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What could I use to keep files synced between my computers without cloud storage limitations?](http://superuser.com/questions/317078/what-could-i-use-to-keep-files-synced-between-my-computers-without-cloud-storage), and related to [How can I keep folders synchronized between several machines over my home network?](http://superuser.com/questions/349/keeping-folders-synced-between-several-machines).

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people who need 2 way sync use [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/).

> Unison is a file-synchronization tool for Unix and Windows. It allows two replicas of a collection of files and directories to be stored on different hosts (or different disks on the same host), modified separately, and then brought up to date by propagating the changes in each replica to the other.
>
> Unison shares a number of features with tools such as configuration management packages (CVS, PRCS, Subversion, BitKeeper, etc.), distributed filesystems (Coda, etc.), uni-directional mirroring utilities (rsync, etc.), and other synchronizers (Intellisync, Reconcile, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to :

- [Synckron](http://synkron.sourceforge.net/), cross platform, easy to use
- [Syncany](http://www.syncany.org/), add the possibility to use cloud's backend to store the files
- [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org/) with a Git backend that allows you to manage versionning of the files